# Is section 13 of the POCSO act read together with section 67-B of IT act 2000?

Tags: indian-penal-code

so the two acts have related provisions in regards to CP offences.

Section 13 of the POCSO act states that

> Whoever, uses a child in any form of media (including programme or advertisement telecast by television channels or internet or any other electronic form or printed form, whether or not such programme or advertisement is intended for personal use or for distribution), for the purposes of sexual gratification, which includes--
> (a) representation of the sexual organs of a child;
> (b) usage of a child engaged in real or simulated sexual acts (with or without penetration);
> (c) the indecent or obscene representation of a child,
> shall be guilty of the offence of using a child for pornographic purposes.
> Explanation.--For the purposes of this section, the expression ''use a child'' shall include involving a child through any medium like print, electronic, computer or any other technology for preparation, production, offering, transmitting, publishing, facilitation and distribution of the pornographic material.

While IT act section 67-B states

> publishes or transmites or causes to be published or transmitted material in any electronic form which depicts children engaged in sexually esplicit act or conduct; or
> (b) creates text or digital images, collects, seeks, browses, downloads, advertises, promotes, exchanges or distributes material in any electronic form depicting children in obscene or indecent or sexually explicit manner; or
> (c) cultivates, entices or induces children to online relationship with one or more children for and on sexually explicit act or in a manner that may offend a reasonable adult on the computer resource; or
> (d) facilitates abusing children online, or
> (e) records in any electronic form own abuse or that of others pertaining to sexually explicit act with children, shall be punished on first conviction with imprisonment of either description for a term which may extend to five years and with fine which may extend to ten lakh rupees and in the event of second or subsequent conviction with imprisonment of either discription for a term which may extend to seven years and also with fine which may extend to ten lakh rupees:]

are the two provisions the same offences falling within seperate definitions of seperate laws ?

The IT act states that nothing in the act should prevent punishment under any other law while POCSO act states that anything in The act that is also an offence under IT act 67B the punishment should be imposed for the law which has a greater punishment. both laws state an overriding effect but pocso act came later and has a higher overriding effect.

> Section 42 A of the Act provides that in case of inconsistency with provisions of any other law, the POCSO Act shall override such provisions.

is IT act section 67-B read together with section 13 of POCSO act ? I tried looking up case laws and found a bunch of bail petitions only.

moreover POCSO act provides for special courts and this is stated in regards to special courts

> The Special Court constituted under this Act, notwithstanding anything in the Information Technology Act, 2000 (21 of 2000) shall have jurisdiction to try offences under section 67B of that Act in so far as it relates to publication or transmission of sexually explicit material depicting children in any act, or conduct or manner or facilitates abuse of children online.

notice how only two of the subsections of IT act 2000 (publishing and distribution and facilitating abusing children online , both of which are covered in 67-B)  are mentioned ? does that mean the other offences like the ones stated in subsections like (b) and (c) of IT act section 67-be would be covered in section 13 of POCSO act ?

edit;; section 13 defines the offence of using children for pornographic purpose while section 14 of POCSO act includes the punishment for the given definition. I've seen various case laws where people are charged with 67B and section 14 , what is the reason for that ? https://indiankanoon.org/doc/183612621/

Comment: Can you use [blockquotes](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#blockquote) when quoting something, please, instead of square brackets. All you need to do is start a new line with the > symbol followed by a space. It makes it a lot easier to read that way. Thanks

Comment: I edited it now

Comment: Please spell out all acronyms used at least once in a post.

Comment: my english sucks my bad. also I'm not used to typing on phone

Answer (score 0):

Both are penalising provisions which have different definitions, POCSO Act governs all media, whereas IT Act is restricted to the cyberspace.

The Criminal Procedure Code (S. 31) provides for several sentences under different laws, with those respective several sentences to run consecutively when not specified, with the option for the court to provide for the sentences to run concurrently.

As regards your question about the decision of which offence is committed, it falls within the domain of facts as both acts have differing definitions.

Nevertheless, see *Central Bank Of India vs State Of Kerala & Ors on 27 February, 2009* for principles applied by the Supreme Court in a case for two acts with overriding clauses.

https://indiankanoon.org/doc/857240/

Comment: thank u for the well written answer. can u answer this question as well pls https://law.stackexchange.com/q/89522/49072

Comment: also do the contents of IT act 67-B also fall under pocso act section 13 ? so as to be same offence under different definitions

Comment: The offences are distinct and one person may be charged with both of them depending on the facts.

Comment: this is late but I've been curious about this for a while. there's a section in the Act which states that anything which is an offence here and also in IPC section 375 and pocso act 67B would be pubishable for which there is greater punishment. what parts of IT act 67b are also punishable under pocso act ? for example there doesn't seem to be any offense related to say possesion in 67B

Comment: If you're reading the section to find commonalities between them, read each sub-clause which has been separated by a list alphabet as a **separate definition of the same offence**. So, even if an accused does not "possess" the incriminating material (taking your example) but does an act that can be incriminating as per the **various criteria for definitions of the offences** in any criminal law, he will be charged with those offences under criminal law. And will be sentenced to the greater punishment of the various offences if the POCSO Act is also charged and he is found guilty under it.